# kotlin - how to modify an integer variable

Tags: kotlin

newbie in kotlin and trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-root-to-leaf-numbers/ with it. hitting a kotlin constraint that declared `val` are `final`

```
/**
 * Example:
 * var ti = TreeNode(5)
 * var v = ti.`val`
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode(var `val`: Int) {
 *     var left: TreeNode? = null
 *     var right: TreeNode? = null
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    fun sumNumbers(root: TreeNode?): Int {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        val pair: Pair<String, TreeNode> = Pair((root.`val`).toString(), root);
        val queue = mutableListOf(pair);
        val res = 0;
        while (queue.isNotEmpty()) {
            // Dequeue a node from queue
            val pair = queue.removeAt(0)
            val (path, node) = pair
            
            if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
                res = res.plus(path.toInt());
                continue;
            }
            // Add left and right child in queue
            if (node.left != null) {
                val tmp = path.plus(node.left.`val`)
                queue.add(Pair(tmp, node.left))
            }
            if (node.right != null) {
                val tmp = path.plus(node.right.`val`)
                queue.add(Pair(tmp, node.right))
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

I get this compile error.

```
Line 28: Char 17: error: val cannot be reassigned
                res = res.plus(path.toInt());
                ^
```

pardon if this has been asked.. But how can i change the line 28 to solve this.

Comment: For mutable variables, use `var` and not `val`.

Comment: So why are you declaring it as `val` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kotlin basic syntax. (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables)

`val` is for read-only variables. it can not be reassigned.
`var` is for variables that can be reassigned.

So, if you want to update `res` value, declare like this.

```
var res = 0
```

And, remember. Kotlin does not need semicolon for instruction end.